# connecting to firebird server from client

Tags: firebird, firebird-3.0, flamerobin

I have a problem connecting to Firebird 3 running on a Windows Server 2012 from a Windows 10 client. Firebird is running on the server and my application is ok and accesses the Firebird database on the server. However it cannot connect to the backup service.

I installed Flamerobin on the client and it cannot connect to the server at all with an "unable to complete network request to host SERVER" error when I run "retrieve server version".

So my application can run using the Firebird database but nothing else can connect to the Firebird server. Why?

On the server itself everything works fine connecting to localhost.

Comment: What kind of connection library does your application use to connect to Firebird? What is the version of `fbclient.dll` on your client (eg by running `instclient  q f` from the command prompt from the Firebird installation folder, or by checking the properties of `fbclient.dll` in `C:\Windows\System32` and `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`)

Comment: I am using IBExpress. My test app can connect to a database with a TIBDataset etc.

Comment: But it fails when connecting to any of the services like TIBSecurityService or TIBBackupService.
Flamerobin fails to connect presumably because it also cannot connect to these services. Flamerobin, FB and my app are all 32 bit using FBClient.dll (or renamed gds32.dll)
Same setup runs fine on a different network. I am no network guru and just accept the defaults when installing FB etc.

Comment: But what is the version number of the fbclient.dll in use?

Comment: Sorry Mark. FBClient.dll is v3.0.2.32703 and FB is the same version.

Comment: Having said that the other installation where everything is fine is running FB3.0.1 (I always look for my errors before suspecting FB)

Comment: 1) IBExpress - the interbase not firebird library - unless patched, uses GDS32.DLL ( or ibtogo.dll for embedded )  2) next thing to try I would compare connection strings in different programs. I guess he uses local connection in one case and TCP/IP connection in another. Or maybe TCPv4 vs TCPv6. Etc.