# Firebird x32-x64 bits

Tags: python, firebird, pyinstaller, 32bit-64bit

I have developed a Python executable programm (with PyInstaller).
This executable use Firebird.

My computer is 64bits, so as my Python and my libraires then.
My executable works perfectly with Firebird 64bits.

The issue is that I want my executable to work on other computers that have only Firebird 32bits installed.

For now, when I try on an other computers the log tells me that (Sorry I have only the picture because my client only send me this and not the 'text' error) :

[image]

Is there a way to make it work with Firebird x32 ?
Thanks

Comment: You could tell client how to copy text. Yet better - your application can help client and make debug-log with all the error text plus basic configuration of computer, and put it into e-mail, so that user only had to press "send" button.

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. The first traceback suggests some parts of your application contain 64 bit libraries (which don't work on 32 bit), the second suggests that an attempt was made to load a 32 bit fbclient.dll, which wasn't found.

Comment: P.S. there is no such thing as x32, there is x86 from Intel 8086/80186/80286/80386/80486 and also Nx586 and Cx686 CPU series.

Answer (score 1):

You application need client libraries of Firebird.

[Application] <--> [Firebird client libraries] <==> (local or remote connection) <==> [Firebird client libraries] <-> [Firebird server]

If your application is Win64, then it needs Win64 client libraries of Firebird to make connection to ANY Firebird server.

So you need to distribute and install client libraries of Firebird matching your application architecture together with your app. Or you may require users to download and install client part of Firebird with the required architecture, before installing your app.

See also:

- [connecting to firebird server from client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43903736/connecting-to-firebird-server-from-client)
- https://firebirdsql.org/manual/qsg10-client-only-install.html
- https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/driver_manuals/odbc/html/fbodbc205-download-fbclient.html
- https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/qsg3-installing.html

Answer (score 0):

If your app is 32bit than you need 32bit fb client dll/so to load, even on 64bit platform. You can connect on any compatible fbserver(regardless 64 or 32bit). So fb client lib(dll) issues are those you need to resolve. If you use fb as embedded library you need only one dll, and it must be compatible with your app binary interface and on 32bit system you need 32bit fbclient.dll to load. I hope this helps.